# Module highlight.js has no exported member HLJSStatic & IModeBase

Tags: vue.js, npm-install, highlight.js

my package.json looks like below,

```
dependencies:
    "highlight.js": "^10.4.0",
    "vue-highlight.js": "^3.1.0",

devDependencies:
    "@types/highlight.js": "^10.1.0",
```

FYI, Its already working fine but i have tried upgrade(Bump updates) im getting this issue.

```
error  in D:/paypayWorkspace/bump-update/developer-panel-web/client/node_modules/vue-highlight.js/dist/types/HLJSLang.d.ts

ERROR in D:/paypayWorkspace/bump-update/developer-panel-web/client/node_modules/vue-highlight.js/dist/types/HLJSLang.d.ts
1:10 Module '"highlight.js"' has no exported member 'HLJSStatic'.
  > 1 | import { HLJSStatic, IModeBase } from 'highlight.js';
      |          ^
    2 | /**
    3 |  * Highlight.js language
    4 |  */

 error  in D:/paypayWorkspace/bump-update/developer-panel-web/client/node_modules/vue-highlight.js/dist/types/HLJSLang.d.ts

ERROR in D:/paypayWorkspace/bump-update/developer-panel-web/client/node_modules/vue-highlight.js/dist/types/HLJSLang.d.ts
1:22 Module '"highlight.js"' has no exported member 'IModeBase'.
  > 1 | import { HLJSStatic, IModeBase } from 'highlight.js';
      |                      ^
    2 | /**
    3 |  * Highlight.js language
    4 |  */

 ERROR  Build failed with errors.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
make: *** [dev-env] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not enough reputation to comment, but I think the answer is that highlight.js updated to version 10.XX.XX and there are some breaking changes so vue-highlight.js is not working anymore.

https://github.com/gluons/vue-highlight.js/issues/66

I have just now realized that you opened the issue there... but I think my answer will help those who land here.

Comment: from my official mail i created that ticket. this one my personal account